# What is causing these multiple HKU\SID entries in the registry on my terminal server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-registry

I have a 2008 R2 terminal server environment with users on thin clients who remote onto three different terminal servers with roaming profiles.

For the last several months, I have been dealing with registry bloating due to HP print drivers. I have followed Microsoft's guides to clean out the bloated keys and apply the necessary hotfixes. However, I am still experiencing bloating. As a result, I have been poking through the registry more on my own, trying to learn more.

One thing that I have noticed on one server is that in the HKEY_USERS hive, when users are logged in, I can see their user hives (as indicated by their SID on the registry handle), but what I am wondering is why there appears to be additional entries, which clearly correspond to an SID, which have numbers contained in curly brackets followed by an incremental number (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) at the end.

I notice that these entries seem to be increasing through out the day. So a user will start off with only one corresponding registry entries, but it will increase to four or more. The multiple entries seem to be exact copies of the main entrie and as a result, my registry is nearing the 2048MB size limit.

I just want to know what this is and why it's happening.
[See image of HKEY_USERS SID entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlPfj.png)

Comment: As you stated,  often it's due to printer driver that refuse to unload. Did you tested with a user account that got only one printer in example, especially not an HP's one ?

Comment: Are you sure? I have noticed that it's not occurring on the other terminal server. All the terminal server users have the same 10 or so printers mapped. By the way, they connect from thin clients and we have printer redirection on (which I don't know if we should or not) and every single printer in Devices and Printers appears twice -- once for the printer, and once for the redirection. Should it be this way? Does that relate to the multiple SID entries in HKU?